# Best way to retrieve data from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I've designed 2 mysql tables something like this.

```
Pages:
+-------------------------------------+
|id page_title   url        created_at|
+-------------------------------------+
| 1  homepage   m.co       2016-04-18 |
| 2  user       m.co/user  2016-04-16 |
+-------------------------------------+

Page Stats:
+-----------------------------------------------+
|id page_id likes comments        created_at    |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| 1   1      10      4     2016-04-18 15:01:54  |
| 2   2      13      13    2016-04-18 15:01:54  |
| 3   1      15      9     2016-04-19 15:01:54  |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

`page_id` in 'Page Stats' table is foreign key of `id` in 'pages' table.
There are like 1000s of Pages & Stats for each url obtained everyday at the end of the day.

I'm trying to retrieve Pages & their stats for some dates sorted by comments (or page_title or comments sometimes) & show it on html table.

I've been doing this

```
SELECT * FROM Pages,Pagestats 
WHERE Pages.id=Pagestats.page_id 
AND DATE(Pages.created_at) >= '2016-03-20' 
AND DATE(Pages.created_at) <= '2016-04-19' 
AND DATE(Pagestats.created_at) >= '2016-04-12' 
AND DATE(Pagestats.created_at) <= '2016-04-16' 
ORDER BY comments desc 
LIMIT 700
```

This works well but I've do some formatting in php side in order to display them in html table like this.

```
id title 2016-04-12 2016-04-13 2016-04-14 2016-04-15 2016-04-15
1  home likes,comms likes,comms  likes,comms likes,comms ...
```

I somehow feel I'm not doing it the right way. For example, the `LIMIT` part, I need only top 10 entries with stats of last 15 days. In this case, `LIMIT 10` wouldn't work for me. How do I tackle this in the right way?

Comment: why don't you prefer join

Comment: Quicker way to say "last 7 days" in MySQL is `DATEDIFF(NOW(),Pages.created_at)<=7`. Back to your problem: It looks like you are looking for grouping by day: `SELECT SUM(Pages.likes), Pages.created_at ... GROUP BY DATE(Pages.created_at)`

Comment: @Ms.Nehal this is a join.

Comment: @cdm , It's not last 7 days always, could change depending on user selection (updated the question).

I don't understand what you said. Basically, what I need is to pull top 10 pages sorted by no. of comments on the most recent day & their stats(likes&comments) for specified range of dates.